# Memory cleanup after active record destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, variable-assignment, model-associations

**Context:**

`Category` has many `Products` and dependent destroy is set in `Category` model for products.

First Case:

```
c = Category.last
c.destroy
c => record persists as expected because it is already loaded in c variable
```

Second Case:

```
p = Category.last.products
Category.last.destory
p => records persisted as expected in p variable as already loaded in this.
```

Third Case:

```
c = Category.last
p = c.products
c.destroy
p => [] ..   Why??
c => record persisted as expected in c variable
```

In third case, Why i am getting blank array for p variable ?

Refer SS.[doubt_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5T6R.png)

Comment: p = c.products..p is a reference

Comment: @sethi I am not able to understand your comment. Can you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: Sure, basically p in the third case is holding a reference to c.products...if after c.destroy statement we do a c.products again we will get a empty array..p is not different than c.products

Comment: @sethi So, I tried this:

c1 = Category.first
c2 = c1.products

c1 = Category.last

Now c2 => Still returns products of c1 as loaded before. Why ??

So, is c2 not a reference here ?

Comment: c2 is still a reference but Category.last is returning a new object..you can try using object_id..like c1 = Category.first c1.object_id c1.products.object_id..c2 = c1.products c2.object_id..and so on to figure out which 2 variables are actually refering to same objects.